# Does the name "Alfero" mean anything?

Tags: history, translation

I know some people who use it as a first name and others who use it as a last name. There is also a place in Italy called [Castell'Alfero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castell%27Alfero) which I understand to mean "The castle of Alfero".

Comment: It is difficult to say whether 'Castell'Alfero' means 'The castle of Alfero', but, FWIW, I think 'Alfero' means nothing but 'Alfero', which is not even a name. Are you sure people you refer to use 'Alfero' as first name? Even if I cannot exclude it exists as surname, I never heard anyone is called 'Alfero', may be 'Alfredo', if any.

Comment: I am 100% sure there is a person with that name. I know him personally. Unfortunately, they don't know either.

Comment: https://familysearch.org/search/record/results#count=75&query=%2Bgivenname%3Aalfero~

Comment: I didn't exclude 'Alfero' may be a surname, nor I excluded that people can be named using invented names, but, anyway, 'Alfero' is not an Italian proper noun. In fact to be sure a name is strictly Italian you have to verify whether it is a name of a Saint of the Catholic Church.

Comment: It seems that the Latin name was *Castrum Alferi*; why it's not clear, as with other toponyms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a variant form of Alfiero, a name of Germanic origin deriving from *athala*, "nobility", and *faraz*, "who guides"; so, all in all, something like “noble guide”. See https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfiero

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to suggest "Alfiere" as a possible derivation for such name. As of the above claim of Germanic origin, according to "Wiktionary" (source: http://it.wiktionary.org/wiki/alfiere), the word comes from the Spanish alférez, which in turns comes from the Arabic al-faris (knight).

Comment: If I understand correctly, they are two (or more) different words that happen to result in Italian into almost equal ones (and perhaps they influenced each other along the way, as often happens). The above “or more” refers to the fact that the *alfiere* as one of the pieces of chess (corresponding in English to the bishop), derives from another Arabic word, *al-fil* (elephant).

Comment: @DaG: in effect the Treccani dictionary says that the original word for the chess piece was [*alfino*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/alfino/), which derives from *al-fil*. This was then altered into *alfiere*.

Comment: Thanks so much @nico. So, which is the answer then? Or you all saying the same thing?